# cattrs.structure with nested dictionaries and attrs.define( converter=foo )

Tags: python-attrs

I am having issues structuring dicts, which contain invalid data, into `@attrs.define` decorated classes, but should be handled with `attrs.define` converters.

I have managed to get it to work with `Foo( **dct )`, which does call the converter for each attribute, but when called with `cattrs.structure( dct, Foo )` or `cattrs.Converter().structure( dct, Foo)` it fails.

It looks to me as the class attriubute converters are not being called.
Is that correct?
Is this a bug in `cattrs` or am I using it incorrectly?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Optional, Any

import attrs
import cattrs


def converter_float_or_none( val : Any ) -> Optional[float] :
    new_val = None
    try :
        new_val = float( val )
    except Exception :
        pass
    return new_val


@attrs.define
class Foo:
    xxx    : Optional[float]   = attrs.field( default=None, converter=converter_float_or_none )


@attrs.define
class Bar:
    foo     : Foo   = attrs.field( factory=Foo, converter=Foo )


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    converter = cattrs.Converter()

    #! --- test with valid fields ---

    dct_valid   = { 'xxx' : None }
    dct_invalid = { 'xxx' : '--' }

    #! ok
    foo = Foo( **dct_valid )
    print( f"foo = {foo!r}" )
    assert None == foo.xxx

    #! ok
    foo = Foo( **dct_invalid )
    print( f"foo = {foo!r}" )
    assert None == foo.xxx

    #! ok !!
    foo = converter.structure( dct_valid, Foo )
    print( f"foo = {foo!r}" )
    assert None == foo.xxx

    #! FAIL !!
    foo = converter.structure( dct_invalid, Foo )
    print( f"foo = {foo!r}" )
    assert None == foo.xxx
```

Output is:

```
(venv_3) $ python3 xxx_test.py 
foo = Foo(xxx=None)
foo = Foo(xxx=None)
foo = Foo(xxx=None)
  + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
  |   File "xxx_test.py", line 54, in <module>
  |     foo = converter.structure( dct_invalid, Foo )
  |   File "/home/brendansimon/venv_3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cattrs/converters.py", line 309, in structure
  |     return self._structure_func.dispatch(cl)(obj, cl)
  |   File "<cattrs generated structure __main__.Foo>", line 10, in structure_Foo
  |     if errors: raise __c_cve('While structuring ' + 'Foo', errors, __cl)
  | cattrs.errors.ClassValidationError: While structuring Foo (1 sub-exception)
  +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
    | Traceback (most recent call last):
    |   File "<cattrs generated structure __main__.Foo>", line 6, in structure_Foo
    |     res['xxx'] = __c_structure_xxx(o['xxx'], __c_type_xxx)
    |   File "/home/brendansimon/venv_3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cattrs/converters.py", line 574, in _structure_optional
    |     return self._structure_func.dispatch(other)(obj, other)
    |   File "/home/brendansimon/venv_3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cattrs/converters.py", line 415, in _structure_call
    |     return cl(obj)
    | ValueError: could not convert string to float: '--'
    | Structuring class Foo @ attribute xxx
    +------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of cattrs. Let me explain what's going on.

The *attrs* converters always get called, there's no way to actually prevent this. The issue here is that *cattrs* tries handling the field before *attrs*, and this fails, since *cattrs* doesn't know about your customized converter.

This is because, in most other cases, *cattrs* skipping its own logic if an *attrs* converter is present would be more surprising.

However, there's a way to enable this:

```py
from cattrs.gen import make_dict_structure_fn

converter.register_structure_hook(
    Foo,
    make_dict_structure_fn(Foo, converter, _cattrs_prefer_attrib_converters=True),
)
```

This snippet is what the `converter` would do itself, we're just doing it manually so we can customize. (The argument name is weird because of other usages of the `make_dict_structure_fn`.)

Looks like we forgot to document this functionality, I'll make a note for the next release.

Here's the entire working snippet (I reformatted with black):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Optional

import attrs

import cattrs


def converter_float_or_none(val: Any) -> Optional[float]:
    new_val = None
    try:
        new_val = float(val)
    except Exception:
        pass
    return new_val


@attrs.define
class Foo:
    xxx: Optional[float] = attrs.field(default=None, converter=converter_float_or_none)


@attrs.define
class Bar:
    foo: Foo = attrs.field(factory=Foo, converter=Foo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    converter = cattrs.Converter()

    dct_valid = {"xxx": None}
    dct_invalid = {"xxx": "--"}

    foo = Foo(**dct_valid)
    print(f"foo = {foo!r}")
    assert None is foo.xxx

    foo = Foo(**dct_invalid)
    print(f"foo = {foo!r}")
    assert None is foo.xxx

    foo = converter.structure(dct_valid, Foo)
    print(f"foo = {foo!r}")
    assert None is foo.xxx

    from cattrs.gen import make_dict_structure_fn

    converter.register_structure_hook(
        Foo,
        make_dict_structure_fn(Foo, converter, _cattrs_prefer_attrib_converters=True),
    )

    foo = converter.structure(dct_invalid, Foo)
    print(f"foo = {foo!r}")
    assert None is foo.xxx
```

Comment: Thanks Tin.
My guess was that `cattrs` was getting in before `attrs` converters were able to run.
I worked around the problem by pre-processing my data first - which was probably more efficient in my case as I single `str.replace()` is all I needed and presumably performs better that lots of individual calls to the converter.
I will investigate customizing the converter as a comparison.
On a side note, I found issues with `converter=MyClass` with `attrs`.  I was getting nested copies in some cases.  Not sure if I was using them incorrectly or not, but I will revisit another time.